# Insert data into table where data comes from two SELECT queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that I need to insert data to. The table has 2 columns:

**ClassStudents (table)**

- ClassId
- StudentId

The data I want to insert can be found from 2 tables:

**Classes (table)**

**Students (table)**

I need to get relevant Classes.Id and relevant Students.Id and insert them to ClassStudents table. I can get the relevant data from each table but I don't know how to insert those data to ClassStudents. The data of the 2 tables won't have the same number of records: Classes will have fewer records than Students, but I need to insert a combination of all Classes.Id to Students.Id and insert to ClassStudents table all those combinations.

I am thinking I need a CROSS JOIN and then use that to insert but I don't know how to or if its even allowed to CROSS JOIN two select queries (one from Classes to get all relevant data and one from Students for also, relevant data).

Comment: Sample data, expected results, and **importantly** *your* attempts will help us help you here.

Comment: please share table structures of classes and students.

Comment: I didn't mention the structure as I just need the Students.Id in Students table and the Classes.Id in the Classes table, as mentioned in the question. A simple SELECT would suffice. The question is how to join two SELECTs together.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide any requisit sample data and the result expected.

However you probably (and if not you'll need to clarify) just need a union

```
Insert into ClassStudents (ClassId, StudentId)
select ClassId, StudentId
from Classes
union
select ClassId, StudentId
from Students
```

If you need to keep duplicates, use `union all`.

Comment: Hi, thanks but as I've mentioned in the question, I need only Students.Id from Students table and Classes.Id from Classes table and then join a combination of those two then INSERT into the table.

Comment: It sounds then like you need a full outer join. It would be a lot easier to help you if you provided proper table schema, sample data and expected results.